# Numpy ndarray multiplication broadcasting error

Tags: python, numpy, multiplication

The following code produces a *ValueError* error. I have tried to reshape/broadcast both *a_minus_b* and *a_minus_b.T* in various ways, but to no avail. The covariance matrix should be a (5, 3, 3) ndarray in this particular case. Any pointers?

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(116966*3).reshape((116966, 3))
b = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
a_minus_b = a - b[:, None] # Broadcast so that substraction succeeds

covariance = np.sum((a_minus_b * a_minus_b.T), axis=-1) / a.shape[0]
```

**Output**

```python
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,116966,3) (3,116966,5)
```

**Desired Output**

```
A 5*3*3 ndarray
```

For clarity, here's the formula that I am trying to implement in python:

[image]

Comment: I am basically trying to calculate covariance (without using np.cov) which is represented by the formula: Sigma((X - Mean)*(X - Mean).T) / n. In my post above, a = X, b = means and these are provided. I need to calculate the covariance using these.

Comment: Pause for a moment and think: what does it mean to "transpose" a 3-dimensional matrix?  If you have a 2D matrix, you can matrix multiply "amb @ amb.T", but with 3D the meaning isn't as clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [55]: a = np.arange(101*3).reshape((101, 3))
    ...: b = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
In [56]: a_minus_b = a - b[:, None]
In [57]: a_minus_b.shape
Out[57]: (5, 101, 3)
```

This is your error:

```
In [58]: a_minus_b * a_minus_b.T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [58] in <cell line: 1>
    a_minus_b * a_minus_b.T
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,101,3) (3,101,5)
```

`*` is element-wise multiplication.  Those shapes don't match.

Where you thinking of some form of matrix multiplication?

We could do `dot` product, using a (5,3,101) and (5,101,3) => (5,3,3), with sum-of-products on the 101 dimension:

```
In [59]: a_minus_b.transpose(0,2,1) @a_minus_b
Out[59]: 
array([[[3045150, 3045150, 3045150],
        [3045150, 3045150, 3045150],
        [3045150, 3045150, 3045150]],

       [[2955159, 2955159, 2955159],
        [2955159, 2955159, 2955159],
        [2955159, 2955159, 2955159]],

       [[2866986, 2866986, 2866986],
        [2866986, 2866986, 2866986],
        [2866986, 2866986, 2866986]],

       [[2780631, 2780631, 2780631],
        [2780631, 2780631, 2780631],
        [2780631, 2780631, 2780631]],

       [[2696094, 2696094, 2696094],
        [2696094, 2696094, 2696094],
        [2696094, 2696094, 2696094]]])
In [60]: _.shape
Out[60]: (5, 3, 3)
```

Comment: hpaulj, thank you! Please see my comment above. I am basically trying to calculate covariance for a ndarray given means in a different ndarray. I do understand that a_minus_b * a_minus_b.T is the problem, but the covariance calculation requires that and I am unsure how to get it to work.

Comment: You can't make `a_minus_b * a_minus_b.T` work.  The shapes don't `broadcast`.  Not that I use a different transpose, one that switches the last 2 dimensions, leaving the `5` at the start.  Then the 'batched' matrix multiplication works.  I don't know if that's what your `coveriance ` requires or not, but that's the kind of calculation that works with these dimensions.

Comment: It sure resolves the error, but the values for the covariance are wrong, unfortunately. I am wondering if it's a problem with my subtraction logic (a - b[:, None]) that's resulting in 2d arrays becoming 3d and causing the problem?

Comment: You are subtracting a (1, 116966, 3) and (5, 1, 3), producing a (5, 116966, 3)

Comment: I actually need to subtract a (5, 3) from a (116966, 3), but that too fails with broadcasting error if done as is (i.e. using just a - b), hence, my attempt to do a - b[:, None]. Not sure if that is correct. Broadcasting properly is not my forte :)

Comment: But how are the `5` and `116966` dimensions supposed to work?  I don't see how, and `numpy` doesn't either.

Comment: Well, welcome to my world :) This is part of an assignment that I am working on and those shapes are provided. And, honestly, the a - b[:, None] logic worked in another part of the assignment with the exact same shapes. It just isn't working for the covariance bit. Apologies for the back and forth, but I really appreciate your help.